# G3m sdk (glob3 mobile) android map and 3d model

Tags: android, 3d, android-mapview

I am working on an android app to display a plane flying over a map and it's trajectory is based on data I read from a file (latitude, longitude coordinates, altitude, roll, pitch, heading). I use the glob3 mobile sdk and used for start their example "3d model'. The problem is when I try to position the plane using setPitch(), setRoll() and setHeading(), the setRoll() and setHeading() are for the same axis only in opposite directions so I can't control one motion of the plane.

If you could look over the code and give me a few ideas on how to change the axis it would be great, I'm not really good with android. Here are the links for the 3d model example provided on github https://github.com/glob3mobile/g3m/blob/purgatory/Android/G3MAndroidDemo/src/org/glob3/mobile/demo/ThreeDModelActivity.java , and here is my code from android studio https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzO0p5utgoipaU9LR25BeWdYcmc/view?usp=sharing

In my app I have 3 buttons to start, pause/resume and stop the animation. I set a camera looking from
270 degrees and I have to use setPitch(90) otherwise the plane will be on a side, actually controlling the roll with that.

Answer (score 0):

These are VEMap references. If you are actually using google maps then please go through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary.html) and use valid GoogleMaps API references.